# Selecting More Than 1 `Select`

Tags: postgresql

Likely already answered, I've searched for it a few times. Likely, I'm not using the right search query.

I want to look up a few different `where` eg, jo, ma, dz, sa

```
select keyword from general_keyword where lang='all of these';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the forum!

You do this by using the [`IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause as follows:

```
SELECT keyword FROM general_keyword WHERE lang IN ('eg', 'jo', 'ma', 'dz', 'sa');
```

If you have a large number of criteria, then you can put them into a table and do something like this (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a23ef70afc4b09591393e76d39295dbc)):

```
CREATE TABLE lang
(
  lang_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  iso_code TEXT NOT NULL,
  lang_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO lang (iso_code, lang_name) VALUES
('eg', 'lang_1'), ('jo', 'lang_2'), ('ma', 'lang_3'), ('dz', 'lang_4'), ('sa', 'lang_5');
```

And then run this query (fairly trivial, but you'll get the idea!):

```
SELECT lang_id, lang_name FROM lang WHERE iso_code IN (SELECT iso_code FROM lang);
```

Result:

```
lang_id lang_name
1          lang_1
2          lang_2
3          lang_3
4          lang_4
5          lang_5
```